# Java Scanner nextInt() asking for input twice

Tags: java, input

I've written the following simple program to read an integer from the console:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter value of n:");
        n = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Value of n is: " + n);
    }
}
```

But I have to enter two inputs for the scanner to read it, even though only the first input is considered. This is the output in the console:

```
Enter value of n:
5
1
Value of n is: 5
```

I've seen a lot of similar questions, but none of them addressed this particular problem.

I know I can do nextLine() and then do a parseInt but I really want to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** A lot of questions being asked about the code. That is the exact code. Also I can confirm that I have observed the same behavior on Eclipse Juno and Kepler.
Check here: i44.tinypic.com/2h83e52.png

Also compile and ran the program outside of Eclipse and still observing the same behavior.
I'm using Java version 1.6.0. Could this be related to that?

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Do you type this in a console, or copy and paste, or what?

Comment: code looks ok,only one input will give your output

Comment: @PaulDraper: I'm typing this in the Eclipse console.

Comment: You've 1 variable to get the 1 input value using the 1 `nextInt()`. I don't see a scope for reading 2 inputs at all. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is the bigger picture here?

Comment: Are you doing this in a loop? If so, add System.out.flush() to flush the console.

Comment: Something you have not mentioned in code, because the same code runs fine without asking two inputs in  eclipse console....?????

Comment: A lot of questions being asked about the code. That is the exact code. Also I can confirm that I have observed the same behaviour on Eclipse Juno and Kepler. Check here: http://i44.tinypic.com/2h83e52.png

Comment: Not sure if this could be the effect of the lingering newline character that is not consumed with `in.nextInt()` What happens say when you add a string to consume the newline character `n = in.nextInt(); String str = in.nextLine();` ?

Comment: @meghamind: Nothing happens. In fact str.length() is 0. I thought it would consume 1. Now I'm curious, where is 1 entered going? Check here:http://i41.tinypic.com/2h2o76u.png

Comment: Hmm. This is weird. What happens when you run from command line? If the same issue persists, I would check java version.

Comment: @meghamind: Same behavior when I compile and run outside Eclipse. I think you're right, the issue seems to be with Java version as others are able to run the same program correctly.

Comment: Were you typing the first number without newline? That would indeed congrue with the described behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are running some other file in eclipse instead of this.